# Center Mutt pager horizontally

Tags: terminal, email, mutt, pager

Is there a way to horizontally center emails when reading them in a larger terminal using mutt?  I'm not interested in centered justification of the text in the email, but I am interested in forcing the block of text to be left-aligned, 78 characters wide and centered in a 120 character terminal.

For example, right now I have something that looks roughly like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| This is an email displayed in mutt.                                          |
| Let's say it's 78 characters wide,                                           |
| even though it's clearly not.  Let's                                         |
| also pretend that the width of this                                          |
| box is 120 characters, which is                                              |
| also not true.                                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is there a way to configure mutt's pager so that it looks closer to something like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                     This is roughly centered text that's                     |
|                     left-aligned and (let's pretend) also                    |
|                     78 characters wide.  I'm not worried                     |
|                     about perfection as much as I am just                    |
|                     getting the text closer to the middle                    |
|                     of the screen.                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've searched the standard documentation, but I haven't found anything.  Should I use something other than the default pager to get this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solutions within Mutt

I'm not finding much in the way of how to do this. Mutt has *_format variables, I suspect you could use those to control `pager_format` and `index_format`, for example:

```
set index_format="%4C %Z %[!%y-%m%d]  %-18.18F  (%4c) %s"
set pager_format="%S [%C] %n (%l) %s"
```

But I don't think this will give you what you want. Also I found a patched version of mutt here, titled: [Mutt sidebar (folder list) patch](http://www.lunar-linux.org/mutt-sidebar/), but again this creates a sidebar and doesn't appear to give you what you want.

[image: ss of mutt]

So I think you might be out of luck, outside of modifying the source of `mutt` itself.

#### Using an external pager?

As an alternative perhaps you could utilize `vim` as a pager for Mutt instead. I found this post titled: [Mark's Mutt Fan and Tip page](http://mark.stosberg.com/Tech/mutt.html).

*excerpt*

> #### Integrates with my favorite text editor.
>
> With Mutt's focus on mail, it doesn't include it's own message editor, but allows me to use one of my choosing. I consider this a feature. Using vim as my editor, I have Mutt configured to allow me to edit the full headers, opening the message with the cursor just below the subject line. For that I've added the following to my `.muttrc` file:
>
> ```
>    set edit_headers
>     set editor="vim +/^$ ++1"
> ```
>
> Editing the full headers is nice because I don't to have to worry about how to add a standard or non-standard header to a message. I can edit them all with the ease I perform other text editing.
>
> On the vim side, I have it configured to recognize the temporary files that Mutt creates as "mail" files, and highlight and format them accordingly. The relevant line in `.vimrc` file looks like this:
>
> ```
>    " set up syntax highlighting for my e-mail
>     au BufRead,BufNewFile .followup,.article,.letter,/tmp/pico*,nn.*,snd.*,/tmp/mutt* :set ft=mail
> ```

With an alternative pager configured you could set the `foldcolumn` in `vim` like so:

```
:set foldcolumn=<width>
```

[image: ss of vim]

**NOTE:** This is a bit of a hack, utilizing the fold column gutter space in this fashion but it works. You're limited to only 12 spaces max with this approach however.

If this doesn't work for you then take a look at a couple of other methods for performing alignment in `vim` in this SO Q&A titled: [how to change the left margin in gvim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893390/how-to-change-the-left-margin-in-gvim).

#### References

- [6. Reference - Mutt documentation](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-6.html)

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response.  You've provided a lot of great information that's close but not quite what I'm looking for.  I'm going to hold off on accepting the response for now since it's not quite a solution to my problem.  It's possible that there just isn't an easy solution to this.  If I don't find one this week, I'll accept this answer and post another comment.  Thanks again!

Comment: @AaronMassey - sure thing, I completely understand. I looked for several hours and couldn't come up w/ anything better, but def. wait. I use mutt too and was surprised this wasn't easy to change.

Comment: I wonder if [VimRoom](https://mikewest.github.io/vimroom) could be of help here.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an entirely ideal solution but if you install [VimRoom](https://mikewest.github.io/vimroom) then you can set your `mutt` pager to `vim` and have it activate `Vimroom`. Set this in your `~/.muttrc`:

`set pager="view -c 'set nomod nolist' -c 'runtime! macros/less.vim' -c ':VimroomToggle' -c ':map q :VimroomToggle<CR>:q<CR>'"
set prompt_after=no`

Here I source `less.vim` which essentially has `vim` behave as a `less`-type pager. The downside of this approach is that there seems to be a conflict with keybindings defined in `less.vim` and in `Vimroom` <strike>, and that an additional keystroke is required when quitting vim to return to the message list in `mutt`</strike>.